# Set dynamic ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys quick question:

If I have an ng-model that should be constructed from multiple variable like receiving some data from a controller:

```
scope.model = 'value[\'passenger[' + ctrl.passenger.passcode + '\']];
```

How can I add this in the ng-model.. because ng-model="{{model}}" won t work..

Comment: You can't use interpolation `{{ }}` inside a `ng-model` because that requires an expression..... What you really want to do is in the directive pre linking phase to set the model...

Comment: I think though you may have to explain what you are trying to achieve here, because it is a little unclear. Like what is `'value'`?

Comment: value is the object where all the data is stored for the form the send

Comment: SO it is an actual object, and `passenger` is also and object? And to access `value`s object you have to use the `passcode` key in the `passenger` object to obtain the key for the `value` object? Am I correct?